# Angular2 access submodule component

Tags: angular, import, module, components

I have an Angular2 application with submodules:

```
├───app (module)                                 
│   ├───authentication (module)                 
│   │   ├───components                  
│   │   │   ├───login                   
│   │   │   ├───sign-in                 
│   │   │   ├───sign-up                 
│   │   │   ├───socials-callback        
│   │   │   └───socials-sign-in         
│   │   ├───models                      
│   │   └───services                    
│   ├───components                      
│   │   └───nav-bar                     
│   ├───home (module)                           
│   ├───shared (module)                          
│   │   ├───components                    
│   │   │   └───search-dropdown         
│   │   └───services                    
│   └───user (module)                             
│       ├───models                      
│       └───services
```

Each components are declared in the `module_name.module.ts` file (of their module).
Each modules files are imported in the `app.module.ts` file.

Here is my `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import ...

import { SharedModule }    from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My `shared.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import ...

import { SearchDropdownComponent } from './components/search-dropdown/search-dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchDropdownComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

When I try to access to SearchDropdownComponent from a template of my app module, I have an error telling my that there is no component corresponding to it.

But when I add the SearchDropdownComponent import directly on my app.module.ts file, it works.

Isn't it possible to access to a component of a sub module?
I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make a component available outside the module, add it the module's `exports` declaration.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import ...

import { SearchDropdownComponent } from './components/search-dropdown/search-dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchDropdownComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SearchDropdownComponent
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

API Reference: [NgModule.exports](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgModule-interface.html#!#exports-anchor)

Also note that a component can belong to only one module.

Comment: Does that mean that if I have a module `A` with two submodules `B` and `C`, if I export `B` component in module `A`, it cannot be used in module `C`?

Comment: You're probably referring to the statement "a component can belong to only one module" - that's true. It means that a component `x` can "belong" (appear in the `declarations`) of either module A, B or C. But this has nothing to do with being able to use it - to use a component `x` in another module, you import the module that exports the component `x`. Let's say you want to use a component that is declared in module B. You export it from B, and import module B in modules A and C.

Comment: Had the same issue, applied this fix and it worked. However, why is it necessary to duplicate `declarations` in `exports`? Is this a performance optimisation?

Comment: @AdrianMoisa, you may want, for instance, to have some components internal to the module - in that case you would not add them to `exports` and that's one reason why the there are separate properties.

Comment: @RonaldZarīts You mean similar to public/private for class methods?

Comment: @AdrianMoisa I guess you can think about it that way. Only what is listed in `exports` is available to other modules.